# Protecting a Save file from modification in a game?

Tags: python, pygame

Currently developping a RPG, I'm asking how could I protect the saved data so that the player/user can't read or modify it easily. I mean yes a person that is experienced with computers and programming could modify it but I don't want the lambda user to be able to modify it, as easily as one could modify a plaintext xml file.

Is there a way I could do that with python?

Comment: You have lambda users?  as opposed to users with names?

Comment: Humm no... I mean users with no programming skills. I didn't know how to put it in my question x)

Comment: Well, typical users don't know about hidden files, so you could try making the save file a hidden file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a cryptography library. This will help you encrypt or decrypt a file using a key. Good thing there is already one called PyCrypto. You can download it [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto).

To use it, once you have downloaded it [It is documented here](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html#new):

```
import string
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Random import random

def gen_cipher():
    # generates 32 letter long key
    key = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 32))
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    return cipher, iv

def write_data(data, rfile, cipher, iv):
    with open(rfile, 'w') as f:
        msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(b'Users cant edit this')
        f.write(msg)

def read_data(rfile, cipher):
    with open(rfile, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        # first 16 bytes are IV
        return cipher.decrypt(data)[16:]

def encrypt_existing_file(infile, outfile, cipher, iv):
    with open(infile, 'r') as if:
        data = if.read()
        write_data(data, outfile, cipher, iv)

def decrypt_existing_file(infile, outfile, cipher, iv):
    with open(outfile, 'r') as of:
        data = read_data(infile)
        of.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cipher, iv = gen_cipher()
    write_data(b"You didn't see anything...", 'file.txt', cipher, iv)
    # ...
    # outputs: You didn't see anything...
    print (read_data('file.txt', cipher))
```

It works by using AES as a symmetric key cipher. First I generate a random key out of 32 randomly chosen ascii letters. Then I create an initialization vector (iv). This is necessary at the *start* of an encrypted file, to initialize properly. Then the cipher itself, which takes a key, an operation mode, and an initialization vector. CFB mode (Cipher Feedback Mode) just means that AES will be used in a way where the next block depends somewhat on the previous block. Udacity has several great videos on [Symmetric ciphers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5soSzzXy8Q), [AES](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ujdCbh7dvA), and [CBC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0D7OwYp6ZEc).

Comment: Hey that sounds like the best solution there !
Will give it a try ! :D

Comment: Just now updated it, so it is a little bit more modular, and may be easier to incorporate into a larger program. Also, do you need to call write_data more than once? If so, let me know so I can modify accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible to encrypt a whole file instead of writing into it ?
I mean if I save the game status XML style, could I encrypt that xml file ?

Comment: yes, you could read the file as a text, then pass the text as data into write_data. Then when you want to decrypt, decrypt the data, and you will have the XML as plaintext.

Answer (score 2):

Just `pickle` or `cpickle` a configuration object with the compression set to max is a quick and easy option.

Comment: Does Shelve have a compression configuration ?

Comment: Pickle uses plaintext though, so editing or modifying would be easy.

Comment: Pickle/Shelve with protocols of 1 or above uses a binary format, a protocol of -1 will use the highest available.  If that is the text syntax it is still likely to be a little obscure if you pickle/shelve objects rather than single values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zlib to compress data.

```
savedata="level=3"

import zlib

#when saving
compressedString = zlib.compress(savedata)

#when loading
loaddata = zlib.decompress(compressedString)
```

Comment: That was my first idea. Will try and see.

Answer (score 0):

pickle may be too big. And work strange in some cases.
ZIP allows to read-write data from different parts of archive.

try zip with password or change first bytes of file to prevent normal unpack

PS. Make some different variants and check size/speed